# On VBA excel 2010, i keep getting a runtime error '1004' where the PasteSpecial method of a range class failed

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2010, copy-paste, vba

I keep getting the RunTime Error '1004', which says that my pastespecial method of a range class failed.  All I'm trying to do is cut out 2 ranges and paste them into a cell right next to it so i can create an open, empty range. For some reason, the pastespecial method of the range class failed, and i can't figure out why. Here is the code below:

---

```
Sub ProductivityMacro()

 Dim rDelete As Range

 Dim rCut As Range

 Dim rPaste As Object

 Set rDelete = Range("A:A,C:D,F:J,M:BD")

    rDelete.Delete (xlShiftToLeft)

 Set rCut = Range("C:D")

    rCut.Cut

 Set rPaste = Range("E1")

    rPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ProductivityMacro()

    Dim rDelete As Range

    Dim rCut As Range

    Dim rPaste As Object

    Set rDelete = Range("A:A,C:D,F:J,M:BD")

    rDelete.Delete (xlShiftToLeft)

    Set rCut = Range("C:D")

    rCut.Cut Range("E1")

End Sub
```